# Область видимости функций

Tags: jquery, ajax

Помогите разобраться с областью видимости.
Как мне увидеть функцию **ajaxDelete** из второго файла?

<sub>backend.js (общий)</sub>

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function ajaxDelete() { }
});
```

<sub>pages.js</sub>

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.delete-entity').click(ajaxDelete);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```html
<script src='jquery.js'></script>
<script src='backend.js'></script>
<script src='pages.js'></script>
```

<sub>pages.js</sub>

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.delete-entity').click(function() {
        ajaxDelete();
    });
});
```

<sub>backend.js (общий)</sub>

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ajaxDelete = function() { alert('qeqqe'); }
});
```

Comment: ага. я почти что так пробовал, но моя беда была в том, что я писал `var ajaxDelete = ...`

Comment: @toxxxa, эх вы любители `var` :) Он нужен для приватной переменной в текущей функции

Comment: а есть ли способ как-то определить вручную `scope` чтоб не засорять глобальное пространство? или обычно не заморачиваются, а просто дают имена своим функциям которые точно ни с чем конфликтовать не будут?

Comment: @toxxxa, все пишут по разному, в основном это говнокод, в котором люди через пару недель сами не разберутся в своём коде. Не обязательно прописывать везде var